# Understanding the motherboard beeps from laptop

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I just bought an ASUS N550j Netbook. It is beeping randomly without a dependency of anything and also the sound is muted. So i guess it's coming from the motherboard. There is nothing related to beeps in the manuel. I have found some beepcodes in the internet but i don't even know which beep is the long and which beep is the short beep. Is there a reference for this beeps? (:D) I didn't observe any problem while using the laptop during 1 day. But it still distress me to hearing that beep. Should i worry about it?

It beeps once for less than one second.

I will update the question after trying the suggestions in below answers.

Edit: I have run hardware dignostics with Asus Software Tool and all peripherals have passed the tests including the memory. I also tried to update the bios but it warned me that it already has the same latest version.

What am i supposed to do now?

Comment: When exactly is the beep happening? Only during bootup, before Windows loads? If not, this has nothing to do with the motherboard's beep codes.

Comment: In the normal operation. Not for the bootop or windows loads.

Comment: In that case, your question has nothing to do with 'boot' or 'motherboard'.

Comment: Sorry i just found a similar question and decided to ask it in here. Is this wrong place to ask it? Sorry for the inconvenience. I mean, are you meanin "there is not a problem with my mother board"? or are you meaning "you can not ask it here"?

Comment: And there is nothing related to "beep" in the keywords.

Comment: You can certainly ask it here. All I'm saying is that your problem is not related to booting up or to your motherboard, as it is only happening once Windows is running. The sound is most likely coming from a Windows program. Your keywords are incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So i should try to find what causes this issue. Actually i had not installed any program at first it was still beeping. And the beep is not coming from the speaker. It beeps even if i mute the sound. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Beeps are typically the PC trying to tell you something. If you hear the beep with the speakers muted, then it suggests the beep is coming from the motherboard itself. Run hardware diagnostics, specifically memory tests, and update your question with results. It may also be a good idea to update your BIOS. Updated BIOS often fix many hardware level bugs.

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank your for the suggestions. I'm starting to research how to do those works and I will update the question with new results.

Comment: @CharlieRB I have updated my question.

Comment: At this point, unless someone is able to answer your question with actual experience with this exact model and issue, I believe you need to call ASUS.

Comment: I will call them monday, thank you for the help.